# Android: move view exactly to the touchpoint

Tags: android

I want to move a view exactly to the touchpoint. Right now Im this far:

```
        relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            moveMe.animate().translationX(x).translationY(y).setDuration(500).start();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

But the view is not in the centre of touch. What should I do?

Comment: do you want it to be where his center is on the point of click or where is top left point is on the clicked point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android coordination system is top-left anchored. So, you should move the view to

```
int x = (int) event.getX() - moveMe.getWidth() / 2;
int y = (int) event.getY() - moveMe.getHeight() / 2;
```